# Nested For Loop to copy and rename a worksheet based on a variable

Tags: excel, vba, nested-for-loop

I am trying to loop through a column full of dates, and for each tax year in the column create a copy of a template Worksheet and rename it to the tax year.

The loop for finding and returning the tax year for each cell works and loops through the full range.
The loop for checking if there is already a worksheet named after that tax year works and loops through the full range.

The problem occurs once I combine the loops.
The dates aren't in chronological order so:
the first 23 dates are for 2023 and 1 Worksheet for 2023 is created,
then there are 3 dates for for 2022 and 1 worksheet for 2022 is created,
then the next date is for 2023 and the For loop to check the existing sheet names fails and it tries to create another worksheet for 2023 returning

> Run Time Error '1004': That name is already taken. Try a different one.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Createtaxyears()

'I'm teaching myself so apologies for poor layout/grammar with regards to my code.

Dim cell As Range
Dim Todate As Range

Dim Sort_Table As Worksheet
Dim Template As Worksheet
Dim WSheetfound As Boolean

Dim Template As Worksheet
Dim WSheet As Worksheet

Set Todate = Range("Sorttable[To Date]") 

Dim Tdate As String
Dim M As Variant
Dim I As Variant
Dim Y As Variant

Set Template = Sheets("Template")

Sheets("Sort_Table").Select  'selects source worksheet to start

For Each cell In Todate  'loop to find tax year

    If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then 'avoids runnin git on empty cells
        Tdate = cell.Value
    
        M = Split(Tdate, ".")  'dd.mm.yyyy is not recognised as a date need to use split to ref
        If M(1) >= 5 Then Y = M(2) + 1  ' tax year returns run from May to April
        If M(1) <= 4 Then Y = M(2)      'I'll turn this into a function later
    End If
    
    For Each WSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If WSheet.Name = Y Then
            WSheetfound = True
            
        Else
            WSheetfound = False
        End If

    Next WSheet
   
    If WSheetfound = False Then Template.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    If WSheetfound = False Then Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select 'selects last sheet to prevent sort_table being renamed.
    If WSheetfound = False Then ActiveSheet.Name = (Y) 
   
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Add `Exit For` after `WSheetfound = True`

Comment: Thank you! Thats fixed it. I've been banging my head against a brick wall for 2 days with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a [dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) to determine if a sheet exists.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Createtaxyears()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsTemplate As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngToDate As Range, cell As Range, FY As String
    Dim arDMY, msg As String
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set rngToDate = wb.Sheets("Sort_Table").Range("Sorttable[To Date]")
    Set wsTemplate = wb.Sheets("Template")
    
    ' build dictionary of existing sheet names
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        dict.Add ws.Name, ws.Index
    Next
    
    'loop dates to find tax year
    For Each cell In rngToDate
         If cell Like "##.##.####" Then ' skip non date cells
            'dd.mm.yyyy is not recognised as a date need to use split to ref
            arDMY = Split(cell.Value, ".")
            If arDMY(1) >= 5 Then 'tax year returns run from May to April
                FY = CStr(arDMY(2) + 1)
            Else
                FY = CStr(arDMY(2))
            End If
        
            ' check if sheet doesn't exist
            If Not dict.exists(FY) Then
                wsTemplate.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
                wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count).Name = FY
                dict.Add FY, 1
                msg = msg & vbLf & FY
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    If msg = "" Then
        MsgBox "No sheets Added", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "Sheets added for years" & msg, vbInformation
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, what are the advantages of using a dictionary ? I like ``If cell Like "##.##.#### Then`` much better than ``Not IsEmpty``.

Comment: @captian Efficiency - the dictionary eliminates the need to loop through all the sheets for every cell.