# Using For loop to copy and paste from offset cells to specific locations in different worksheets based on the values found

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, copy-paste

I am trying to write a macro that loops through a sort table, creates a copy of template for each financial year it finds then copies and pastes the data from the sort table into the appropriate cells on the corresponding worksheet.

I have the Sub where it loops through the data and creates a Copy of the worksheet for each financial year.
My previous problem with that can be found at: [VBA nested For Loop to copy and rename a worksheet based on a variable; not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76582456/vba-nested-for-loop-to-copy-and-rename-a-worksheet-based-on-a-variable-not-work/76582950?noredirect=1#comment135027018_76582950)

Now I a new problem, I have written the bit that loops through the Charge Types and returns the Variables I need in order to paste it to the correct Worksheet: Financial Year (Which is what I have named the worksheets), Financial Month which dictates the destination Row and Charge Type which decides the destination column and Cash which is the value I want to copy and paste.

The problem is I keep getting a Runtime 1004 Error: Application-defined  or Object Defined Error.

I have tried various different methods:
`Range(X).Value = Range (Y).Value`
`.Copy Destination:= X`
and `.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`

All yield the same result. I suspect the problem is the way I'm declaring or setting the destination worksheet. But I can't see what I'm getting wrong.

```
Option Explicit


Public Function FY(Fdate As String) As String  'This function extract the Financial Year from a date in ##.##.#### format
Dim arDMY As Variant

arDMY = Split(Fdate, ".")
If arDMY(1) >= 5 Then
    FY = CStr(arDMY(2) + 1)
Else
    FY = CStr(arDMY(2))
End If

End Function

Public Function FM(Fdate As String) As String 'This function extracts the Financial Month from a date in ##.##.#### format
Dim arDMY As Variant
Dim TM As String
arDMY = Split(Fdate, ".")
If arDMY(1) >= 5 Then
    TM = CStr(arDMY(1) - 4)
Else
    TM = CStr(arDMY(1) + 8)
End If

If arDMY(0) >= 5 Then
    FM = TM
Else
    FM = TM - 1
End If

End Function


Sub Move_stuff()

Dim cell As Range
Dim Charge As Range

Dim Sort_Table As Worksheet

Dim C As Variant
Dim D As Variant
Dim Targ As Range
Dim Ddate As Range
Dim Charge_Amount As Range
Dim Targdate As String
Dim Cash As Double
Dim TM As Variant
Dim Pos As Variant
Dim Sheet_go As String
Dim Year As Variant
Dim Month As Variant

Set Charge = Range("Sorttable[Charge Type]")

Dim CType As Object
Set CType = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

CType.Add "Fos", 2
CType.Add "Foo", 9
CType.Add "Bar", "Cash"
'real dictionary contains various types that returns the number of the column I want the data pasted in.

Sheets("Sort_Table").Select  'select worksheet with data in sort table
For Each cell In Charge  'loop to find charge type
    If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
        C = cell.Value
        D = CType(C)
        Set Targ = cell.Offset(, 3)
        Set Ddate = cell.Offset(, 2)
        Set Charge_Amount = cell.Offset(, 4)
        Targdate = Targ.Value
        EDP = Ddate.Value
        Cash = Charge_Amount.Value
        Pos = 16 - FM(Targdate) 
        'this gives me a row where I want data to be copied to. So with R1C1 referencing the range I want to copy to is .Range(Pos, D)
        Sheet_go = FY(Targdate) ' This gives me the year which is what my destination worksheets have been named.

        If D = "Cash" Then
            MsgBox Cash & vbCrLf & EDP & vbCrLf & cell.Row
        Else
            MsgBox FY(Targdate) & vbCrLf & Pos & ", " & D & vbCrLf & Cash 'checks all variables are correct
            cell.Offset(, 4).Copy 'this only works if I don't reference the Worksheetin the range.
            Sheet_go.Select  'selects the destination table and this works as I can see the change in tab.
            Worksheets(Sheet_go).Range(Pos, D).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 
            'this doesn't work returns Runtime Error 1004: Application defined or Object defined error. 
            'Also the xlPasteValues are wrong and don't match the value in cell.Offset(, 4)
   
            Worksheets("Sort_Table").Select 
        End If
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: You've declared `Sheet_go` as String, so it's difficult to see how  `Sheet_go.Select` could work?

Comment: If FY() is supposed to give back the sheet name, FM the row number, then you'll need something like `Worksheets(FY(TargDate)).Cells(Pos,D).Value = cell.Offset(,4).Value` in the Else. You also don't need select for any of this. Try working more with Worksheet variables (I see you even declared one but didn't set it) and in the `With Sort_Table ... End With` block then.

Comment: Worksheets(FY(TargDate)).Cells(Pos,D).Value = cell.Offset(,4).Value worked like a charm. Now I have new and interesting bugs to fix elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Range requires "A1" formula or two Cells(x,y) value.

If you use instead Cells(Pos,D) it works but D must have a valid identifier (edited).

If CType(C) returns an Empty value (no match) then the line fails.

Comment: "D must have a valid number" - D can also be a valid column letter eg `Cells(1, "F")` is fine.

Comment: "D must have a valid number". D will always have a valid number. ''' If Not IsEmpty(cell)''' covers that, and I'll add code for "If not in dictionary then X ". I'm getting the basic functions working before worrying about exceptions. I'll try changing it to '''Worksheets(Sheet_go).cells(Pos,D).PasteSpecial''' and see of that works.